# Inconsistent behaviour from MonoObjects

Tags: c++, mono

I have embedded mono inside a c++ game engine to be used with my component system. Currently, I store the MonoObjects (instances of the components) using entt like this:

```
struct ScriptsComponent
{
    // Components (scripts) that exist in the C# runtime (ie. user generated components)
    std::unordered_map<std::string, MonoObject*> externalScripts; // Name of type, ptr to object in C# runtime

    // Components that exist both in the C# runtime, and C++ runtime (ie. Engine intrinsic components)
    std::unordered_map<std::string, MonoObject*> internalScripts; // Name of type, ptr to object in C# runtime
};
```

Using that, I can for example get field values from components, by passing in MonoObjects that I retrieve from entt with the `ScriptsComponent`, and using functions like:

```
template <typename T>
static T GetComponentValue(MonoObject* componentObject, const std::string& fieldName, MonoDomain* domain)
{
    MonoClass* klass = mono_object_get_class(componentObject);
    const char* name = mono_class_get_name(klass);

    MonoClassField* field = mono_class_get_field_from_name(klass, fieldName.c_str());

    MonoObject* fieldObj = mono_field_get_value_object(domain, field, componentObject);

    return  *(T*)mono_object_unbox(fieldObj);
}
```

Or setting values:

```
static void SetFieldValue(const char* fieldName, MonoObject* object, void* value)
{
    MonoClass* klass = mono_object_get_class(object);
    if (klass) {
        MonoClassField* field = mono_class_get_field_from_name(klass, fieldName);
        mono_field_set_value(object, field, value);
    }

}
```

This all works fine, and I can correctly pass data between the managed side and unmanaged side. However, after running the program for a while (a minute or so), the MonoObjects 'break'. Either I can't get the `MonoClassField*` anymore, or the vtable field of the MonoObject is nullptr. I thought that maybe the object were being garbage collected, so I tried adding `mono_gchandle_new(object, false)`, after creating the object, but that did not work. Any ideas as to why I cant access the object fields anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the objects were being garbage collected of some sort, so pinning the object by using `mono_gchandle_new(object, true);` appears to have fixed the problem.